# Finding all paths from a single node in a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG) using LISP

Tags: search, lisp, directed-acyclic-graphs

I am having some issues figuring out a solution using lisp for the problem detailed below.

This is one of my Homework problems for Artificial Intelligence that deals with converting an un-directed graph into a directed acyclic graph and then applying a search on it for all-paths from a given node.

The problem body is as follows:

> Problem 1:  Consider the example graph used in class to 
>   illustrate different search algorithms. Our original graph 
>   was undirected. Make it directed, and assume that the
>   following form sets the directions between the nodes:
>
> ```
> (setf
>   (get 's 'successors) '(a d)
>   (get 'a 'successors) '(b d)
>   (get 'b 'successors) '(c e)
>   (get 'c 'successors) '()
>   (get 'd 'successors) '(e)
>   (get 'e 'successors) '(f)
>   (get 'f 'successors) '())
> ```
>
> Successors are not ordered in any way. Let the nodes in
>   this directed graph represent tasks, each of which takes a 
>   known amount of time, defined by the following setf form
>
> ```
> (setf
>   (get 's 'time-consumed) 3
>   (get 'a 'time-consumed) 2
>   (get 'b 'time-consumed) 4
>   (get 'c 'time-consumed) 3
>   (get 'd 'time-consumed) 3
>   (get 'e 'time-consumed) 2
>   (get 'f 'time-consumed) 1)
> ```
>
> Also, let the directed edges represent precedence relations 
>   between nodes, such that if there is an edge from task A to 
>   task B, then task A must be completed before work can begin on 
>   task B (this is the topological ordering problem that you
>   are familiar from CS 253/CS 501)
>
> Write a procedure, ALL-PATHS, that returns a list of all 
>   non-circular paths starting from a given node. For example,
>
> ```
> (all-path 's)
>
> ((S A D E F)
>  (S A B E F)
>  (S A B C)
>  (S D E F))
> ```
>
> HINT: EXTEND function must be changed to use the SUCCESSOR 
>   property (rather than the NEIGHBORS property). To get all 
>   incomplete paths to the front of the queue, use SORT together 
>   with FIRST-PATH-INCOMPLETE-P, a predicate that returns T if 
>   the first of its two arguments is an incomplete path, i.e.
>
> ```
> `(defun first-path-incomplete-p (p1 p2)
>    (not (endp (extend p1))))`
> ```

From there I have this so far:

```
(setf
  (get 's 'successors) '(a d)
  (get 'a 'successors) '(b d)
  (get 'b 'successors) '(c e)
  (get 'c 'successors) '()
  (get 'd 'successors) '(e)
  (get 'e 'successors) '(f)
  (get 'f 'successors) '())

(setf
  (get 's 'time-consumed) 3
  (get 'a 'time-consumed) 2
  (get 'b 'time-consumed) 4
  (get 'c 'time-consumed) 3
  (get 'd 'time-consumed) 3
  (get 'e 'time-consumed) 2
  (get 'f 'time-consumed) 1)

(defun all-paths (start)
  )

(defun extend (path)
  (print (reverse path))
  (mapcar #'(lambda (new-node) (cons new-node path))
    (remove-if #'(lambda (successor) (member successor path))
      (get (first path) 'successors))))

(defun first-path-incomplete-p (p1 p2)
  (not (endp (extend p1))))
```

In addition I modified the graph she refers to from class to reflect the new relationship:

[image: DAG]

My issue is really how to approach this using lisp and how I might use the procedures she wants such as `extend` and `first-path-incomplete-p`. The examples I could find online involve a source and destination whereas I am trying to find all-paths from a single node.

In addition using a source and destination I know that best-first search or even depth-first could be beneficial for this problem however I am stuck when it comes to applying them with only a starting point.

Any help, suggestions, or comments are appreciated!

Thanks

---

**Update**

I had huge success after some slight modifications. Not sure why, but it just clicked for me. I ended up modifying a best-first search implementation I did on a previous homework and now generate all paths from a single node. Not sure how necessary the `cond` statement is, but the relevant changes occurred here:

```
(defun closerp (path-1 path-2)
  (< (get (first path-1) 'time-consumed)
     (get (first path-2) 'time-consumed)))

(defun all-paths (start &optional (queue (list (list start))))
  (cond ((endp queue) nil)
    ;((equal start (first (first queue)))
    ;(reverse (first queue)))
  (t (all-paths start
    (sort (append (extend (first queue))
      (rest queue))
        #'(lambda (p1 p2)
          (closerp p1 p2)))))))
```

The only thing left is to implement `first-path-incomplete-p` which I think will tighten my results a bit seeing as I am getting more paths than intended with her example of `(all-paths 's)`

For instance, when I do the same query I get this:

```
Break 1 [2]> (all-paths 's)

(S) 
(S A) 
(S A D) 
(S A D E) 
(S A D E F) 
(S D) 
(S D E) 
(S D E F) 
(S A B) 
(S A B E) 
(S A B E F) 
(S A B C) 
NIL
```

These are all valid paths, however it doesn't select the same paths that her example illustrated which to me look like optimal paths.

Comment: One important thing to improve readability of code is proper indentation. Use the editor for that...

Comment: I updated the indentation to a hopefully more readable version